# Issues with Alchemy getContractMetadata endpoint

Tags: nft, nodejs, alchemy

I have created a new ERC-1155 NFT collection for my project but for some reason Alchemy's getContractMetadata endpoint does not recognizes it at all.
I'm filtering by contractAddress: 0x0bdde5fd11a87850915975ce153066bacf95cb77 and the response is

```
{
    "address": "0x0bdde5fd11a87850915975ce153066bacf95cb77",
    "contractMetadata": {
        "name": "",
        "symbol": "",
        "totalSupply": "",
        "tokenType": "UNKNOWN"
    }
}
```

Querying the same endpoing with contractAddress: `0x1d3ada5856b14d9df178ea5cab137d436dc55f1d`
works.
Is that a bug in the endpoint?
I'm using node.js and fetching the request with axios.
endpoint URL is `https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/nft/v2/<ALCHEMY_API_KEY>`
I can supply the contract ABI / bytescode of the smart contract if needed
Here's the collection on opensea: https://opensea.io/collection/valee-example

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct network? In that case perhaps is a limitation of the provider. Try asking to their customer support.

Comment: Yes I am connected to the correct network.
Already opened a ticket in their Discord Support, waiting for a reply and I'll update findings here, thanks!